# '서울에는 인사동 있어요 ' can this also be the correct sentence for Insadong in in Seoul or I should just say ' 인사동은 서울에 있어요'?

Tags: grammar, spoken-korean, korean-to-english

Are both the sentences correct and can be used? I did the translation on several apps and '서울에는 인사동 있어요 ' was translated as There is Insadong in Korea.

Comment: First one sounds more like Seoul has Insadong while the 2nd one is more like Insadong is in Seoul

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- First, try not to learn Korean (or any other language) using automatic translators.  They have many errors and frequently omit subtle nuances altogether.  So if you try to answer "How are phrase X and Y different?" using these translators, you will end up chasing random noise.

In "서울에는 인사동이 있어요", the topic is *Seoul*.  It is more alike "In Seoul, there is Insa-dong," or "In Seoul, you will find Insa-dong."  It would be a natural answer if the question was "What are the best known places in Seoul?"

(I think it's better if you add -이 after 인사동: it's possible to omit that, but that sounds a bit too clipped here.)

In "인사동은 서울에 있어요", the topic is *Insa-dong*.  So it is a more natural match for "Insa-dong is in Seoul," or if the question was "Where is Insa-dong?"